# Array of structs in C and ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I am trying to set up an array of structs that will eventually print off 6 boxes using ncurses. First problem is i dont know how to set up an array of structs, and my second problem is, i dont know how im supposed to draw the boxes. An extra thing about the boxes is that they must be drawn using the "|" key for the vertical walls, and i need to use "-" for the walls going horizontally. I have tried to malloc memory for an array of structs using:

```
room * roomInfo = malloc(sizeof(room) * 6);
```

with room being my struct name and roomInfo being my array of structs. I am getting three errors with this. One is "error: unknown type name 'room'" and the other is "error: 'room' undeclared (first use in this function)" (at the top of my file i have: "struct room roomInfo;") and the third being "note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in"

```
typedef struct 
{
int roomNumber;
int height;
int width;
int eastDoor;
int westDoor;
int southDoor;
int northDoor;
}room;
```

Comment: Why `malloc()`? Just use a plain old array of struct: `struct room roomInfo[6];`

Comment: Do you have a `typedef struct {...} room;` somewhere? Can you show what it is? It doesn't sound like the compiler has seen it by the time it encounters the lines with the problem.

Comment: I changed it so im not using malloc, I also added my struct to the code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing wrong: the following minimal code compiles without errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
int roomNumber;
int height;
int width;
int eastDoor;
int westDoor;
int southDoor;
int northDoor;
}room;

int main(void) {
room *roomInfo;
roomInfo = malloc(6*sizeof *roomInfo);
}
```

Most likely: your definition of `room` is not known at the time that you declare `room *roomInfo;`. Is it in a `#include`?