# Segmentation fault, structs, ncurses, drawing

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ncurses

I am getting a segmentation fault in my code. My code is:

```
#define STARTING_POINT 5
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
input(argc, argv);
parser(argc, argv);
drawingRooms();
return 0;
}


void drawingRooms(room roomInfo[6]) 
{
int rooms;
int i;
int positionX;
int positionY;
rooms = 0;
initscr();
noecho();
for(rooms = 0; rooms < 6; rooms++)
{
    switch(rooms)
    {
        case 0:
        for(i = 0; i <= roomInfo[rooms].length; i++);
        {
            move(STARTING_POINT + i, STARTING_POINT);
            printw("|");
        }
        break;
    }
}   
getch();
endwin();
}


void parser(int argc, char **argv)
{
FILE * rooms;
char * theString;
char * theToken;
int width;
int length;
int k;
int x;
int placeInt;
int posX;
int posY;
char a[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];
item gold;
item monster;
item potion;
item hero;
item stairs;
room roomInfo[6];
rooms = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if(rooms == NULL)
{
    printf("error opening file\n");
}
x = 0;
while(fgets(a, ROOM_STRING_LENGTH, rooms) != NULL)
{ 

    theString = malloc((sizeof(char)*(strlen(a)+1)));
    strcpy(theString, a);

    for(theToken = strtok(theString, " "); theToken; theToken = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        sscanf(theToken, "%dX%d", &length, &width);
        roomInfo[x].roomNumber = x;
        roomInfo[x].width = width;
        roomInfo[x].length = length;

        if(theToken[0] == 'd')
        {
            switch(theToken[1])
            {
                case 'e':
                {
                    placeInt = theToken[2] - '0';
                    roomInfo[x].eastDoor = placeInt;
                    break;
                }
                case 'w':
                {
                    placeInt = theToken[2] - '0';
                    roomInfo[x].westDoor = placeInt;
                    break;
                }
                case 's':
                {
                    placeInt = theToken[2] - '0';
                    roomInfo[x].southDoor = placeInt;
                    break;
                }
                case 'n':
                {
                    placeInt = theToken[2] - '0';
                    roomInfo[x].northDoor = placeInt;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                } 
            }       
        }

        else if(theToken[0] == 'g' || theToken[0] == 'm' || theToken[0] == 'p' || theToken[0] == 'h')
        {
             k = 0;
             while(k <= (strlen(theToken)))
             {

                 switch(theToken[k])
                 {
                     case 'g':
                     posY = theToken[1] - '0';
                     posX = theToken[3] - '0';

                     gold.Xposition = posX;
                     gold.Yposition = posY;
                     break;

                     case 'm':
                     posY = theToken[1] - '0';
                     posX = theToken[3] - '0';

                     monster.Xposition = posX;
                     monster.Yposition = posY;
                     break;

                     case 'p':
                     posY = theToken[1] - '0';
                     posX = theToken[3] - '0';

                     potion.Xposition = posX;
                     potion.Yposition = posY;
                     break;

                     case 'h':
                     posY = theToken[1] - '0';
                     posX = theToken[3] - '0';

                     hero.Xposition = posX;
                     hero.Yposition = posY;                  
                     break;

                     case 's':
                     posY = theToken[1] - '0';
                     posX = theToken[3] - '0';

                     stairs.Xposition = posX;
                     stairs.Yposition = posY;   
                     break;
                 }
                 k++;
             }
        }
        else if(theToken == NULL)
        {
            printf("end of file");
        }
    }

    if(theToken == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
    x++;
}
free(theString);
fclose(rooms);
}
```

and my struct is:

```
typedef struct 
{
int roomNumber;
int length;
int width;
int eastDoor;
int westDoor;
int southDoor;
int northDoor;
}room;
```

What i am trying to do is access the first struct in my array of structs, then do something with the information ive acquired. Whenever i run the following code, nothing is printed and i get a seg fault

Comment: what is `STARTING_POINT`?

Comment: Are you in the same class as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22411757/1967396)?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but if this is going where I think it's going (where you're going to add some or all of cases 1 to 5 to the `switch`), you might have the [loop-switch antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence) here.

Comment: starting point has been updated, and i most likely am in the same class as that guy

Comment: Could you show the `room roomInfo[6]` array that you are pushing in to this function? Maybe the function, through which you are calling this `drawingRooms`

Comment: Okay, either I don't know C, or there is something truly extraordinary there. What exactly are you hoping to have by calling `drawingRooms` function with **no arguments**, at all?

Comment: I updated my code, I am trying to get access to the information that i stored in the array of structs roomInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable you create, remains alive until the corresponding closing curly bracket `}` of the opening curly bracket `{` before it.

Each pair of opening and closing curly brackets and the contents within `{ ... }` are referred as *code blocks*, and with this definition, we can say that a variable remains alive within the code block it is declared.

You are declaring one `roomsInfo[6]` array inside the function `parser`, and it looks like you are hoping to be able to access it directly without doing anything from another function: `drawingRooms`

Things won't work out like that.

One another thing, a C compiler shouldn't be allowing you to call a function that asks for an argument, without an argument. So you shouldn't be able to make the call `drawingRooms( );` at all, for `void drawingRooms( room roomInfo[6] ) { ... }` defined like that. In case it does allow, then it probably regards `room roomInfo[6]` as an un-initialized variable, like this:

```
    void drawingRooms(  )
    {
        room roomInfo[6];
        ...
    }
```

Anyway, what you should be doing is to feed the `drawingRooms` with an appropriate argument, which would be the address, the pointer to the first element of the array of 6 `room` structures; if you have declared its function like that.

To resolve this specific issue, you have two options, I'll start with the easy one:

### 1) Making `roomInfo[6]` a file-scope variable

By making the `roomInfo[6]` a global (file-scope) variable, the variable will live through the whole life-time of the programme, thus will be accessible from everywhere in the code. To do this:

- delete the line `room roomInfo[6];` inside the `parser` function
- remove the argument `room roomInfo[6]` from the function `drawingRooms`
- declare `room roomInfo[6];` above everything else, above the `main` function

Like this:

```
    #define STARTING_POINT 5

    //somewhere above the roomInfo declaration, somewhere here
    //there has to be the typedef for the room structure,
    //either through the inclusion of a header file
    //or the typedef struct {...} room; itself

    room roomInfo[6];

    int main( ... )
    {
        ...
    ...
```

### 2) Pushing the pointer to the `drawingRooms`

To do this, you'll have to first allocate memory for the array of `room` structures yourself, so that it won't get killed automatically when the `parser` function ends; then return the pointer to the first element with the `parser` function, use that returned address while calling the `drawingRooms` function:

- replace the line `room roomInfo[6];` with `room * roomInfo;` in the `parser` function
- allocate 6 `room` structure-worth memory for your rooms

Like this:

```
    roomInfo = calloc( 6, sizeof * roomInfo );
```

- make sure you have included either `<stdlib.h>` or `<malloc.h>`, for the `calloc` call
- add this line at the end of `parser` function: `return roomInfo;`
- change the return value of `parser` function from `void` into `room *`
- use this return value inside the `main` function while calling the `drawingRooms` function

Like this:

```
    //either like this:
    ...
        input( argc, argv );
        drawingRooms( parser( argc, argv ) );
    ...

    //or like this (allows you to free it inside main):
    ...
        room * roomInfo;
        input( argc, argv );
        roomInfo = parser( argc, argv );
        drawingRooms( roomInfo );
    ...
```

- if your programme is to run further, make sure you `free` the allocated memory.